# Is there a way to change a gif into a jpg but still maintain animation properties?

Tags: jpeg, gif, animated-gif

I've found in a couple of places where normally only jpgs would be accepted, that users have uploaded gifs instead. What I think is going on, is that they're changing some of the code in the gifs to proxy a jpg and thus bypass systems which usually only take a jpg file. Is there a specific way to change a gif's header information to somehow imitate a jpgs?

I'm experimenting to see the logic behind this. I've noticed that among all the code found in gif files, they usually begin with a 'GIF89aoo'string. Anybody familiar with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can jpg images support animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844805/can-jpg-images-support-animation)

Comment: JPEG's do not support animation.

Comment: I never said jpgs support animation. I'm fully aware jpgs by their nature are static, although the ajpg format has tried to introduce animation. What I am asking is specifically, has anybody ever tried changing the data in a gif to make it read as a jpg by a system, but still function as a gif. Locally, I have changed the gif extension to jpg, and the gif animation would still play. I have seen in spotify where users have uploaded animated  gifs, even though the system only accepts jpg or png. I am assuming they have tricked the system to think their gifs are jpgs. Has anybody tried this?