# can a jpeg have an animation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, animation, jpeg

can someone please tell me how can i make a jpeg like this that is animated
https://oss-pk-arab.badambiz.com/icon_8323870_d2d3b09a2e7a94ea0753b5bdce7f53b3.jpeg
even trying to save it to your pc gets rid of the animation so i suspect its done with code?

Comment: Hi, make sure to check if the question you are about to ask has not already been asked on Stackoverflow before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844805/can-jpg-images-support-animation

Answer (score 0):

> can a jpeg have an animation?

Yes: while the JPEG file format (i.e. [JFIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)) does not support animation or multiple frames, there *is* "[Motion JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)" which refers to a variety of file-formats based on sequential JPEG image/frames.

***However!*** - The animated image you linked to is actually an **animated GIF in disguise**: despite the `.jpeg` filename extension in the URI and the webserver *incorrectly* serving the image with `Content-Type: image/jpeg`, if you download the 1.8MB file and use a hex editor, you'll see it's a GIF file, and a GIF editor can reveal the frames:

[image]

---

Visible GIF animation frames in a GIF editor:

[image]

---